# Is Sequelize Typescript column data type not strict?

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am using an SQLite database with Sequelize. On top of Sequelize, I am using [Sequelize-Typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript). I have defined a table and gave every column a specific DataType. I assumed that it would then also validate that upon adding rows or updating rows, it would check whether the data indeed is of that DataType. However, after testing, I could add an instance with a boolean in a column with the DataType STRING(128).

Is this normal behavior? If so, what is the correct way to validate input datatypes?

Comment: did you have answer for this, i also have the same issue?

Comment: Well... yes.. but its not incredibly pretty. The datatype is (to my knowledge) only a syntactical thingy for your compiler/linter. What you can do to check at runtime is to add a 'validator' function. Although you can add the standard validators, you can also check for types using custom validator functions.